# wxPython continiuouly update panel

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython

I am new in wxPython and can't solve one problem. I need to continuously update panel with clock value. I have a solution, but in this case I can't normally close window (alt+f4 not works).
Also I do not unsderstand what is the difference between .Update .Refresh and when .Destroy should be called?

Can some one reccomend a good book, how to program in wxPython?
Thanks for any help.

```
class TimeDatePanel(wx.Panel):
def __init__(self, parent, ID=ID_TIMEDATE, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(50, 50), controller=None):
    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, ID, pos, size, wx.RAISED_BORDER)
    self.controller = controller
    transCoded = controller.transCodes
    layout = wx.GridSizer(5,2,0,10)
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, transCoded.get("Time & Date")))
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, ""), 0,flag=wx.ALL)
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, transCoded.get("Local time")), 0,flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.LT = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    layout.Add(self.LT)
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, transCoded.get("UTC")), 0,flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.UTC = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    layout.Add(self.UTC)
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, transCoded.get("Julian day")), 0,flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.JD = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    layout.Add(self.JD)
    layout.Add(wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, transCoded.get("Local sidereal time")), 0,flag=wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
    self.LST = wx.StaticText(self, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    layout.Add(self.LST)
    self.SetSizer(layout)
    self.updateTimeDate()
    self.Fit()

    wx.EVT_PAINT(self, self.onPaint)

def onPaint(self, event=None):
    self.updateTimeDate()

def updateTimeDate(self):
    mechanics = self.controller.mechanics
    self.LT.SetLabel(str(mechanics.getLT()))
    self.UTC.SetLabel(str(mechanics.getUTC()))
    self.JD.SetLabel(str(mechanics.getYD()))
    self.LST.SetLabel(str(mechanics.getLST()))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need the clock updated every so often, why not use the AnalogClock, LEDNumberCtrl or maybe the TimeCtrl that's updated with a wx.Timer? The following tutorial will help you with the timer part: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/

The first two widgets update themselves. You should have to call Update, Refresh or Layout when you rest a value of a StaticText control or other normal widget. Just use SetValue or SetLabel instead.

Robin Dunn has an older book called "wxPython in Action" that is still great for the most part. There's also a wxPython Cookbook by Cody Precord that came out this year.